# merge by id and column name in R

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge two data set into one using id and column name as indices.

I have the following data

```
df <- 

    a b c d e f g id
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2  2
    3 3 3 3 3 3 3  3
    4 4 4 4 4 4 4  4

panel_empty <- 

id df_id df_data df1_data df2_data df3_data
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
1   e
1   f
1   g
2   a
2   b
2   c
2   d
2   e
2   f
2   g
3   a
3   b
3   c
3   d
3   e
3   f
3   g
4   a
4   b
4   c
4   d
4   e
4   f
4   g
```

I would like to merge these somehow to look like this

```
panel_full <- 

id df_id df_data df2_data df3_data
1   a      1
1   b      1
1   c      1
1   d      1
1   e      1
1   f      1
1   g      1
2   a      2
2   b      2
2   c      2
2   d      2
2   e      2
2   f      2
2   g      2
3   a      3
3   b      3
3   c      3
3   d      3
3   e      3
3   f      3
3   g      3
4   a      4
4   b      4
4   c      4
4   d      4
4   e      4
4   f      4
4   g      4
```

I only know how to merge by id but have no idea how to merge by id and column name. For panel data data this is quite important to do and I was surprised not find any similar problem on this site.

EDIT:

So far, I was able to convert from wide to long

```
long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("id"))
```

However, I do not know to move on.

I tried

```
m1 <- merge(panel_emtpy, long, by.x = "id", by.y = "df_id")
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the "wide" `df` to "long" form before attempting to merge. Search for "long to wide" conversion.

Comment: @r2evans Hi, thank you for the suggestions. I manged to do so, but do not know how to move on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `dplyr` and `tidyr::gather()` -

```
panel_full %>%
  left_join(gather(df, df_id, df_data, -id), by = c("id", "df_id"))
```